# Segmentation Fault en C

Tags: c, segfault

Tengo este programa al que se le insertan dos números (a y b) y el programa lee y guarda en un arreglo todos los números entre a y b incluyendo esos mismos, después imprime el último digíto de cada uno de los números del arreglo.

Cuando coloco números menores a 9 no me lanza ningún error, pero si lo intento con 10 o mayor me lanza ese error. ¿alguien sabe a que se puede deber?

Gracias

Siempre inserto números de 6, como de 1 a 5 o 10 a 15

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){
int a,b,i;
int arr[6];

/*Solicita ambos números*/
printf("\nEscribe dÃ­gito a: ");
scanf("%d",&a);
printf("\nEscribe dÃ­gito b: ");
scanf("%d",&b);


for(i=a;i<=b;i++){arr[i]=i;
printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
}


for(i=a;i<=b;i++){int num=arr[i]%10;
printf("Prueba: %d\n",num);
}
printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Si tu array es de 6 `int`, porque así lo has definido, solo puedes acceder desde `arr[0]` a `arr[5]`. Si la `i` llega a valer más de 5 tendrás un problema porque estarías accediendo a una zona de memoria que no es tuya, y el resultado de eso es impredecible. Solo definiste espacio para 6 enteros.

Comment: Tienes razón, gracias!!